# Mirror RHEL repositories

Tags: centos, rhel

I'm attempting to install Spacewalk 1.8 with mrepo and create a mirror of RHEL 5&6 packages to use for frequently spun up development VMs.  There are several guides that indicate I should use mrepo with gensystemid to register individual repositories as systems on RHN and then use the entitlements granted to my rhel systems.  However gensystemid fails because /usr/share/rhn/RHN-ORG-TRUSTED-SSL-CERT is not present.  It's not clear to me where I get this cert, whether it is included with an official rhel install, or if it is pulled in after using rhn_register, or if this the "key" per se that you purchase with the Satellite product that allows you to mirror?  Several unhelpful how-to's say it's included with CentOS and it is not, nor is it present in rhn-tools rpm.

Comment: As this is marked CentOS, I'll assume you are running Centos, and don't have a contract with Red Hat. In that case, use the CentOS repos; or contact Red Hat for a support contract and access to their repos.

Comment: I do have several systems registered with RedHat as well as CentOS and I have no problem using RedHat entitlements to pull the data.  I installed on CentOS because I am using Spacewalk. The issue is I can't use mrepo to perform the registration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears mrepo is broken and/or abandoned.  I am forced to use createrepo as described here: [createrepo with rhel satellite](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/sec-Creating_a_Yum_Repository.html).  This means I have to have 2 rhel servers, one for 5 x86_64 and one for 6 x86_64 to create my local repos.  This consumes the same number of entitlements but requires an additional vm, but at least it will work with some longevity.  In my case the 6 repository will be on the same server hosting spacewalk but I will have to manually set up http from the 5 repository so it can be used as well.